# A splinter error: Driver not found error, why does it say this?

Tags: python, splinter

I'm completely new to splinter and quite new to python. I wanted to do a splinter program to automatically log me in to websites once I run the program on a computer. I searched the web a bit for splinter, and I created a program to try and open a web browser and search something in it. However, this error appears:

```
================= RESTART: C:/Users/hp/Desktop/splinterexp.py =================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hp/Desktop/splinterexp.py", line 4, in <module>
    browser = Browser()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\splinter\browser.py", line 123, in Browser
    raise DriverNotFoundError(f'Driver for {driver_name} was not found.')
splinter.exceptions.DriverNotFoundError: Driver for firefox was not found.
```

This is the code I put in:

```
from splinter import Browser


browser = Browser()

browser.visit('http://google.com')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Splinter documentation](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drivers/firefox.html), `firefox` is the default browser. And according to the error message you provided, you don't have the Firefox web driver installed.

So, you'll either want to install [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver), or specify a browser you do have a web driver installed for.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/driver_install.html) wasn't very clear to me (...) but try this:

```
python -m pip install selenium
```